# What specifically does "rollback" mean?

Tags: discussion, badges

In the description for the cleanup badge, it says to earn this badge, you need to have your first "rollback", yet when I search rollback on the internet, I get "a reduction or decrease". I do not understand what this means. May someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Other users can edit your posts (e.g. to fix typos). If you disapprove of their edit to your post, you can "rollback" the edit, which basically means "undoing" their edit. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback

Comment: Although, just something to mention (because I see your suggested edit on another question) - on Puzzling.SE, sometimes questions intentionally use typos to hide information relevant to the puzzle. It is usually a good idea to ask if the typo(s) are intentional before fixing them.

Comment: Oh, ok then. How did you see that?

Comment: Did you just happen to bump into that question?

Comment: When you suggest an edit, it goes through review. Then users with sufficient reputation can view your suggestions and approve/reject them. This is to ensure the quality of edits.

Answer (score 2):

See [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) for the specifics. Essentially, you and other users are allowed to edit your posts (questions or answers). Sometimes you change your mind about your own edit, or you disapprove of another's edit. In these cases you can "rollback" the edit, returning the post to its state before the edit was made.

As an example commonly seen on Puzzling.SE, suppose User A creates a puzzle, and User B edits User A's puzzle to fix some typos. But it turns out, that User A intended for there to be typos in order to hide a clue relevant to the puzzle. So User A may rollback User B's edit.

It seems you have mistaken the "Critic" badge for the "Cleanup" badge. To get the critic badge, you must place a downvote. (Please don't do this to a random post just to get the badge.) To get the cleanup badge, you must rollback an edit.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it